# Server was unable to process request. ---> Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'

Tags: server, was

The request failed with the error message:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'.
```

This is my code:
    --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>

<style type="text/css">

<!--

body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}

fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 

h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}

h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 

h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 

#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;

background-color:#555555;}

#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}

.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}

-->

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>

<div id="content">

 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>

  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>

  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>

 </fieldset></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>



--.
```

Comment: Add some context - when did you get that error? Show some configuration, request headers, etc. - anything related to that content type part of error

Comment: What programming language? What server? Apache httpd? What does the server error log contain? What does your application log file say?

Comment: .net Console application,IIS8 server,tls 2 web service consuming that time the getting above exception